# Get count for questions from audit log

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two tables one table A contains question and other Table B have the log for all the question asked.
I want to get the count for each question in Table A.
The catch here is Question can be in any of the  4 columns

Below is table A

[image]

[image]

thanks
Sanjeev

Comment: Why do all the columns have the same name in `A`?  Please edit the question and show the results you want.  Why does the table not use the `id` column in the second table?

Comment: sorry my mistake, the Column name is different

Comment: . . You should fix the question.  In addition you should put the data in as *text tables* not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use a lateral join and aggregation:

```
select submenu, count(*)
from a cross join lateral
     (values (a.submenu1), (s.submenu2), (a.submenu3), (a.submenu4)) v(submenu)
where submenu is not null
group by submenu;
```

You could also use a `join` and aggregation:

```
select b.question, count(*)
from b join
     a
     on b.question in (a.submenu1, s.submenu2, a.submenu3, a.submenu4)
group by b.question;
```

Comment: great @Gordon, let me run and  check